# Mocking a static function call with a long chain of calls in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, testing, mocking

I'm trying to test a large legacy Django application, and I'm getting confused by Python mocking as I have never worked on large Python application.

Specifically, I have method has a long call chain inside that generates an array:

```
def update(self): # in some class X
    # ...
    for z in foo.models.Bar.objects.filter(x=1).select('xyz'):
        raise Exception("mocked successfully")
```

I'd like to mock the `foo.models.Bar.objects.filter(x=1).select('xyz')`.

**Attempt 1**

I've tried several approaches gleaned from various questions, notably using a decorator:

```
@mock.patch('foo.models.Bar.objects.filter.select')
def test_update(self, mock_select):
    mock_select.return_value = [None]
    X().update()
```

I never hit the inside of the mocked call, however- the test should fail due to the exception being raised.

**Attempt 2**

```
@mock.patch('foo.models.Bar')
def test_update(self, mock_Bar):
    mock_Bar.objects.filter(x=1).select('xyz').return_value = [None]
    X().update()
```

**Attempt 3**

```
@mock.patch('foo.models.Bar')
def test_update(self, mock_Bar):
    mock_Bar.objects.filter().select().return_value = [None]
    X().update()
```

**Attempt 4**

I then tried something more basic, to see if I could get an NPE, which didn't work either.

```
@mock.patch('foo.models.Bar')
def test_update(self, mock_Bar):
    mock_Bar.return_value = None
    X().update()
```

All of my attempts pass the test, instead of the exception firing like I expect it to.

It's late so I assume I must be overlooking something basic in the examples I've seen!?

Comment: What's your import of `Bar` inside class `X` look like? Do you just have `foo` imported like this? `import foo`

Comment: Just `import foo` like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to have it pass by mocking objects. Attempt #3 is close, you just need to change it to `filter.return_value.select.return_value` to have it pass. Here's my suggestion though as it seems mocking `.objects` is the preferred way.

```
@mock.patch('foo.models.Bar.objects')
def test_update(self, mock_bar_objects):
    mock_bar_objects.filter.return_value.select.return_value = [None]
    X().update()
```

EDIT: Test run output:

```
ERROR: test_update (test_x.TestDjango)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wholevinski/.virtualenvs/p2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1305, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "/home/wholevinski/so_test/django_mock/test/test_x.py", line 10, in test_update
    X().update()
  File "/home/wholevinski/so_test/django_mock/foo/x_module.py", line 6, in update
    raise Exception("mocked successfully")
Exception: mocked successfully

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Comment: Clarification- I'm trying to hit the exception in my example code. At least for me running it, your code passes the test instead of hitting the exception.

Comment: Added the test run output, I am seeing that error like you're expecting.